# Is there a way to prevent an Activity from being removed from memory while it is in the background?

Tags: android, android-activity, garbage-collection

I built a media playing app with controls in Fragments. The main Activity hosts all these Fragments. These Fragments keep a reference to the main Activity and call methods in the main Activity when there is a control change.

Now I need to prevent the main Activity from being gobbled up while it is in the background. What is the best way to make this possible?

Currently, my research makes it look like I will need to move just about all my main Activity code to a main foreground service and have forwarding methods in the main Activity. Is that how it needs to be done or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to make this possible?

It's not.

> my research makes it look like I will need to move just about all my main Activity code to a main foreground service and have forwarding methods in the main Activity.

Your foreground service will be responsible for playing the music. Your UI (activity/fragments, `Notification` with `MediaStyle`, app widgets, etc.) will send commands to the service to tell it how to change the playback (pause, skip tracks, change volume, etc.).

> Is that how it needs to be done

Yes, if you want your media playback to continue while your UI is in the background.

Comment: The media style only works with ```Build.VERSION_CODES.O``` and higher. I put a custom layout in the notification and was going to have the buttons link up to the service through broadcasts.

Comment: @JohnGlen: "The media style only works with Build.VERSION_CODES.O and higher" -- no, it will work back to API Level 21 at least (Android 5.0). The [framework one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle) was introduced then, and `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` might offer some sort of backport for older devices.

Answer (score 0):

simply no

---

u can use background services for that
refer this video https://youtu.be/3EQWmME-hNA